# Data mining outlier removing and PCA

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, pca

I need a dataset for some operations such as data cleaning,outlier detection and removing, Principle component analysis but I couldn't find any dataset.

Also , I made outlier removing 2 columns dataset. I really don't know how can I make this with multi column.

Do you have any suggestions for datasets and methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it a try with below datasets for PCA. They must have some outlier and some cleaning stuff to do.

https://data.world/exercises/principal-components-exercise-1

Comment: Thanks for your help!!